# Change the color of the line select in datatables using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I have a datatable with lines and i would like when i click on a row i would like to change background-color: red from the select line and the other lines i would like to leave with a background-color: white

I try with this :

```
$(document).on('click', "#table_user tr:not(:first) td:first-child", function() {
var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1; 
 if(row_num == $(this).closest('tr').index()+1){

          $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
        }else{
          $(this).css({'background-color':'white'});
        }
});
```

But it does not work

Comment: The if condition will always result in true.

Comment: All lines are white at start?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the `if` condition will always result in `true`. You can do something like:

```js
$(document).on('click', "#table_user tr:not(:first) td:first-child", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

And then, for the `.selected` class, you can style it based on even or odd:

```css
.selected:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.selected:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: @sebastianlarsen Depends on how you implemented it. Can you show us a [mcve]? JSBin.com is a good start.

Comment: @sebastianlarsen Can you please show me a [mcve] so that I can help you. Use JSBin.com and share me the working / non-working page.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want this to happen on all rows except first row, this will work:

```
$("#table_user td").on('click', function() {
  var row_num = parseInt($(this).parent().index()) + 1;
  var cell_num = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
  if (row_num != 1) {
    if(cell_num == 1) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
  } 
  else {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Well, not sure how this works as `if (row_num == $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1) {` will always be true. Isn't it?